# Python adding to dictionaries .csv format

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to add a new key:value to a CSV file in Python. The new values for the key come from the values of existing keys in the table.

```
def addKey(allData):  
    allData = []  
    for i in range (0, len(allData)):  
        while i > 0 and allData[i] == allData[i+1]:  
            newKey = {}  
            newKeyVal = int(allData['key1']*100 + allData['key2'])  
            allData = dict(allData, newKey = newKeyVal)  
    return allData
```

Any suggestions? I have a feeling this code is all wrong to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If `allData` is already a dict, then you would want

```
allData["newkey"] = newKeyVal
```

IIRC, dicts will only let you have one of each key, so as long as "newkey" doesn't already exist in the dictionary it will just add it.

You probably don't want

```
allData = []
```

in there either.

Comment: Thanks, I've made these changes so far, however, I am now getting "IndexError: list index out of range"  for this line:   while i > 0 and allData[i] == allData[i+1]: